# Axios normal GET request progress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

### What I am trying to do:

I am using ***Vue And Axios***, I am trying to show the progress in percentage in the console.

## Problem is:

The request itself take 4 seconds or maybe more because it get lots of data and store it to an excel then ***Download it***.

## What I have tried:

I have found two methods in ***Axios***: `onDownloadProgress` and `onUploadProgress`.

The `onDownloadProgress` function works fine but only when the download start not while the back-end is fetching the data to an excel file (Which take the most of the time).

## Here is the front-end code:

```
axios.get(`${env.ENDPOINT}reports/products/credits_export`, {
    params: {
      category_id: form_data.category_id
    },
    responseType: 'blob',
    onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
      let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
      console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable);
      console.log(percentCompleted);
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    const file_name = `${new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)}.xlsx`;
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', file_name);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    resolve(res.data);
  }).catch((e) => {
    reject(e);
  });
```

### SUMMER:

My progress will be divided into two:

- Download progress (Will use the `onDownloadProgress`)
- Request progress (Which is getting the Excel file ready for download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know how much time will server take to respond you can't show the percentage of progress bar at that point of time, If it is a stream kind of data we can show progress, For this as you can simulate such kind of effect before making a call set state of you progress bar to show and then put some random percentage in a set Interval method then after getting the response recalculate and continue the progress status from that point.

```
this.progress =true;
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
this.progressPercentage = randomFunction()
 // some random calculation for progress
},500)
axios.get(url)
.then(()=>{
   clearInterval(interval);
   // User your progress event object 
})
```